# What is the name of a component that combines a switch with a variable resistor?

Tags: resistors, switches, control

I had some lights with a rotating switch that would turn them on/off, and then continuing to turn the switch would make them brighter. What sort of switch is this called? (it had a physical "click" to it between switching on and off).

Comment: Lack of effort to find it at digikey... or anywhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's just a variable resistor with a switch. It doesn't have a specific name to distinguish it from variable resistors without a switch.

Comment: What would I search for to find one on like [digikey](http://www.digikey.com/product-search/en/potentiometers-variable-resistors/rotary-potentiometers-linear/262965?k=variable%20resistor%20with%20a%20switch) or [mouser](http://www.mouser.com/Passive-Components/Potentiometers-Trimmers-Rheostats/_/N-9q0yi?Keyword=variable+resistor+with+a+switch&FS=True)?

Comment: @user2813274, did you even try at digikey... there is a selection that says single with switch... jeesh (-1)

Answer (score 4):

I think you're being a bit hard on the OP- it's a potentiometer with a switch. If s/he were looking for a switch with built-in potentiometer the pickings would be slim.

Answer (score 3):

It's called a "switched pot."

Google "switched pot" for a zillion hits